# Pc booting to a drive that’s no longer plugged in

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot

I plugged my old laptop hard drive  into my pc and it booted into my laptop I got the files I needed. Then I shut it down and unplugged it and now it’s still trying to boot as my laptop. Not sure what to do

Comment: Change the boot order in the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to access your computers BIOS settings and change the boot order. Google: "How to access  BIOS". It's usually:

1. shutdown computer
2. start computer and tap F2 (I tap it at a rate of about 2/second)
   If it's not F2, try Delete.

Within the BIOS, you'll find the boot order somewhere. Each BIOS is organized differently, but there's usually a BOOT menu somewhere with the order. I suggest you checkout YouTube and search "How to change boot order". A visual example will likely help you if you get stuck. If you have to, you can dig into Google and find instruction specific to your computer.

Once this is done, you can save your changes to the boot options by exiting and saving the BIOS changes as you do. On my system, this is done by hitting F7, but there's always an Exit (will prompt to save) or an Exit & Save option somewhere in the BIOS menu.